# How to swap GridView with ListView in the same Activity with the same ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing an application which displays a list of domain models. The default behavior is displaying those models in a `ListView`. I'm planning to let the users swap between seeing this data as a list or as a grid using a `GridView`. What is the idiomatic way to do so?

My domain model is a simple pojo, I created a `CustomArrayAdapter` for it and a custom row layout which currently looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label"
        android:text="@+id/text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I wish to use the same `ArrayAdapter` for both layouts.

The layout of my activity is rather simple:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- what do I put here? -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't share the Adapter, share the data. Have a different adapter for the grid and the list, and just use the same backing data for both adapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just always use a gridview, and set the columns to one for your "ListView" mode using

`android:numColumns` or `setNumColumns(int)` via code?

More info : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: I see. This looks good! And how do I swap the row layouts when I set the numColumns? I'll need 2 different representations for list and grid.

Comment: ahh.  for that you might need to edit to your Adapter Class and add a method to swap handle/reference to the layout file you want to use. You could also subclass GridView and override `setColumns` to then call that new CustomArrayAdapter method to swap the layout handle/reference. And then call its notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

This awesome library is a game changer https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList