# how to use listview and gridview in same activity

Tags: listview, android-activity, gridview

```
I have an activity that contains LISTVIEW with some text data and below that i had GRIDVIEW with some set of data.Now i have to scroll whole activity.
```

For example if my listview contains 20 text data then i cant able to scroll beyond listview so cant see my gridview content. I have to scroll whole activity not specific of list or grid.

I had use below xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sampletext.SampleText" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ListView>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView and GridView, both comes with default scrolling features. I guess you cannot use both at a time, better you can switch each other. You can keep a **Button** or **FloatingActionButton** and switch from listview to gridview and vice versa. For switching you can refer this

[How to swap GridView with ListView in the same Activity with the same ArrayAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323639/how-to-swap-gridview-with-listview-in-the-same-activity-with-the-same-arrayadapt)